# If a female is meeting a non mahram in a room, who should the mahram be with her?

Tags: women, men, non-mahram

> No man should be alone with a woman and vice versa, there should be a
> third person.

So the third person should be a male or a female? What should be the relationship between the third person and the woman?

Answer (score 1):

The third person's relation to the woman is not specified. He only has to be her mahram. It could be her any mahram.

Answer (score 0):

The woman must be accompanied by a male mahram in the company of a non-mahram who will act as her guardian

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would best to have a mahram with you a male to be safe to keep track on what’s going on